# Special cases of solving a square root

Tags: radicals, irrational-numbers, square-numbers

Are there cases where solving a square root, which you can move the coefficient inside the √ to yield a rational answer, but cannot yield one if you leave the coefficient on the outside.

I imagine that there are no such instances, but I'd be delighted to see a proof, is this just re-phrasing $a^2 + a^2 = b$ or is there something else too it, I am a student in High School and have a limited knowledge of certain number theory concepts.

**Just to clarify, I mean this in the sense that the number inside the root is a square number, I understand that either way you'd get the same result, I apologize for my poor framing of this.**

Comment: So did I understand correctly, you want numbers $a$ and $b$ so that
$$
b \sqrt{a}
$$
is irrational, but $$ \sqrt{ba} $$ is rational? Or how?

Comment: not exactly, you know how when you shift a coefficient into a root you square it, I want numbers such that √a is irrational but √b^2*a is rational number.

Or more probable, a proof that there is not such pair.

Comment: Does $a=2, b=1$ do  what you want?

Comment: No? Perhaps I didn't phrase it correctly but √1^2*2 is just √2 which is irrational.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Any number irrational multiplied with a perfect square is irrational. It's only possible only when b is also irrational.

Comment: Can $b$ be an irrational number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret you question correctly , you want two rational numbers $a,b$ such that $\sqrt a = \text {An irrational number }$ while ${b}\sqrt {a}$ or $\sqrt {a {b^2}} = \text { A rational number.} $ This obviously False as :

Let us assume that $b\sqrt{a}$ is rational . Then , :

$$b\sqrt a = \frac pq$$ for some rational number $p$ and $q.$

Then :

$$\sqrt a = \frac{p}{bq}$$

Since R.H.S is rational , this implies that $\sqrt a$ is also rational which contradicts the fact that $\sqrt a$ is actually irrational.

This completes the proof.

If $b$ can be irrational , then this possible by taking $b = \sqrt {a^3}$.

Now $$b\sqrt a = \sqrt {ab^2} = \sqrt {a^4} = \boxed{\color{blue}{ a^2 }}$$

which is rational.